# How to generate the coverage report using mocha in vs code?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, code-coverage

Am using mocha to run the unit tests for my node js application.
I use the following command to run the test cases.

```
npm run mocha test/controller
```

test/controller is the test class package.

Below is a sample code of the unit test.

```
const controller = require(./controller);
describe("execute", =>{
  sinon.stub().restore();
  const req= {name:"tina", dob:"2-12-2000"};
  it("call method to post" =>{
  const res = controller.result();
//test fails in the below line
  sinon.assert(axios.post,"http://dummyurl/login,req);
 });
});
```

When executed the test case it shows only the number of tests passed and not the coverage report with percentages like below table.

```
✓ call method to post

  1 passing (5ms)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |   58.33 |       50 |      50 |   58.33 |                   
 Producer.js   |   33.33 |      100 |       0 |   33.33 | 7-17              
 controller.js |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 6                 
---------------|---------|----------|---
```

Can someone please help?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: JUnit is a _Java_ testing tool. Have you done any configuration to try to get coverage?

Comment: I have not added any configuration to get coverage. Ive used mocha to run the test cases. Could you please elaborate if am missing anything in this part?

Comment: Yes, you're missing... any configuration to get coverage! I'd suggest doing some research around the coverage tooling available and how to integrate it into your testing (e.g. right on the Mocha homepage there's https://mochajs.org/#wallabyjs).

Comment: Thank you so much... will check it..

Comment: How did you get teh coverage report that is showing there?

Comment: I replaced junit with unit.  I think that must have been an accident

Comment: Hi Alex028502 .. the unit report which ive pasted above is a sample from another application which generates the report. But i didnt know how it got generated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a report like you are showing on the command line, this will probably work:

```
$ npm install nyc
$ node_modules/.bin/nyc npm run mocha test/controller
```

`nyc` is a wrapper for `istanbul` that you can wrap around almost any command and get a coverage report.

But I don't understand how you got the coverage report you are showing us, and where vscode fits in.